# react native certain images not shown

Tags: react-native

I'm playing with react native and starting to build my first app.
I render 3 images to the screen.
One is displayed while the other 2 are not.
The urls are 100% valid and opened properly when pasting the address in browser.
The Image component is created in a a loop so all of them are identical besides the uri.
What can be the problem?

```
<View style={[styles.flex1, styles.imageRow, {backgroundColor: 'orange'}]}>
                {images.map((d, i) => (
                    <View key={i} style={[styles.flex1, {borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'black'}]}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('Image', {uri: d, coachName})}>
                            <Image source={{uri: d}} style={{height: 100, width: 100}}></Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>))}
            </View>
```

working image url:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/judoka-6de90.appspot.com/o/borochov1.jpg?alt=media&token=13f09af6-e8a9-42bc-bf8f-dee58891cca7

not working:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/judoka-6de90.appspot.com/o/coaches%2Fliran1.jpg?alt=media&token=28738b27-dcdb-4c55-8af0-93413b6c6ea6

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/judoka-6de90.appspot.com/o/coaches%2Fliran2.jpg?alt=media&token=301f176f-5f94-422b-a80e-ec059d091059

Answer (score 0):

reducing the images size solved the issue.